# Is Link based on Peter Pan?

Tags: video-games, disney, the-legend-of-zelda, peter-pan, character-similarity

[image]

I stumbled across this comparison between Link (Nintendo) and Peter Pan (Disney).

Both:

- have a fairy companion
- wear green tunics and pointy green hats
- have elf-like pointed ears
- play a small whistle-like instrument
- lived in a forest with a group of children who never grew old
- have fought their own shadow
- are much shorter in height than their arch-nemesis
- can defy gravity with the aid of magic (Link uses magic hover-boots, Peter Pan uses magic fairy dust)
- are not affected by time the way others are (link sort of time travels, Peter Pan lives in Neverland where time can't affect him)

#### Did Nintendo base Link on Peter Pan?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Yes. Shigeru Miyamoto is a fan of Disney and drew upon Peter Pan for inspiration when creating Link for the Legend of Zelda.

> Interestingly, Link bears a resemblance to Peter Pan, as they are both elf-like, wear green clothing, fight with swords, and are sometimes accompanied by a Fairy. Link also fights his shadow in some games, either Dark Link or Shadow Link, just like Peter. (...)
>
> Shigeru Miyamoto, the creator of the Legend of Zelda series, has stated that he used Peter Pan as a bit of an inspiration for Link's design in The Legend of Zelda. - [source](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Link#Attributes)

<sup>Additional sources can be found [here](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2012/11/the_legend_of_zeldas_link_was_inspired_by_walt_disneys_peter_pan) and [here](https://nintendoeverything.com/link-design-inspired-by-peter-pan-name-explained/).</sup>

Another fun piece of trivia:
Take the famous opening 3 notes of [Zelda's Lullaby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKLAUNc58iA&list=PL9A7FA60D25750CE1&index=18), reverse the order of the notes and you get the [3-note tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S55JMQlsLmw) Peter Pan plays in the Disney film!

[image]